# Growing in the Tropics

Tags: plant-recommendations, flowers

Can I grow peonies, camellias or magnolias in the tropics/Philippines? or at least a good substitute for those I have mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Magnolias will probably be fine, there are pink and white ones which I grew successfully in Hawaii. You might want to keep the ground clear around the base of the tree and make sure it has adequate drainage. Peonies generally need a hard freeze, and since the roots are sensitive to transplant you can't just stick them in the freezer. I'd say no on that one. But you might be able to do Chinese tree peonies (also rather lovely). Camellias? They should go fine. There are varieties in the Southern US and Indonesia.